# How to calculate number of characters of monospace font that fit into div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code like this:

```
div {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

$(function() {
    var div = $('div');
    var space = $('<span>&nbsp;</span>').appendTo(div);
    var num_chars = div.width() / space.width();
    var chars = '';
    for (var i=0; i<num_chars; ++i) {
        chars += 'd';
    }
    div.html(chars);
    space.remove();
});
```

but number of characters is way to small to fill the width of the div. Anyone know how to calculate the number of characters that will fill one line of a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution that works was using getBoundingClientRect to get real float width of one character and then just use width of the container divided by width of the character:

```
function get_char_size(div) {
    var temp = $('<span>&nbsp;</span>').appendTo(div);
    var rect = temp.find('span')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var result = {
        width: rect.width,
        height: rect.height
    };
    temp.remove();
    return result;
}
function get_num_chars(div, char_size) {
    var width = div.width();
    return Math.floor(width / char_size.width);
}

var container = $('.container');
var size = get_char_size(container);
var chars_per_line = get_num_chars(container, size);
```

there are two functions because if you don't change font size you can calculate char size only once and second function can use each time you resize the container.

Answer (score 3):

**How to Calculate CPL**

[image]

Use JS to get the width of the div where `75` would become a variable as well as your fontsize and container width.  But this is the formula.

- 75 = Desired CPL
- 16 = Fontsize
- 2.28 = Char Constant - In your case this will be the monospace font's char const
- 526.3158 = PX of container.

Make a function to manipulate this formula to get your answer.

[Read more >](http://www.pearsonified.com/2012/01/characters-per-line.php)

Comment: The formula is based on an assumption on the (advance) width of characters in a monospace font, with respect to font size. It is a guess/assumption/estimate, no more. There is no reason to rely on such issues if you intend to do things with JavaScript, where you can access the *actual* width.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general method, which uses [getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getClientRects) to determine when the contents overflow to a new line.  [normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize) seems to be needed for `getClientRects()` to function properly.

I'm using `word-wrap: break-word` to avoid the need for multiple spans.

You can also simplify the `for` loop by using the `Array().join()` method I use:

```js
var space = $('<span>').appendTo('div'),
    num_chars;

do {
  space.append('M');
  space[0].normalize();
} while (space[0].getClientRects().length === 1);

num_chars = space.text().length;
$('div').html(Array(num_chars).join('d'));
```

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the simple approach is that although the advance width of a character is constant in a monospace font, it is generally not an integer number of pixels. It is defined in a much more fine-grained manner in the font file, typically using a unit that is one thousandth of the font size. Browsers deal with this in different ways. The code in the question behaves differently in different browsers.

For consistent results, set up an inline element, insert it inside the `div` element, and add characters to it until its width exceeds the width of the container; then just remove the last character. This is rather easy in plain JavaScript:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var len = foo.offsetWidth;
var span = document.createElement('span');
foo.appendChild(span);
span.innerHTML = '';
for(var i = 0; span.offsetWidth <= len; i++) 
  span.innerHTML += 'd';
span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.substring(0, span.innerHTML.length - 1);
```

```css
span, div {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px; /* kept this, though it is irrelevant */
    /* line-height: 14px; omitted here as irrelevant */
}
```

```html
<div id=foo></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the number of characters without actually use innerHTML? I need to calculate this on window resize and my browser freeze when I resize.

Comment: I don’t think you can get a reliable value without actually creating an element that contains sufficiently many characters. You can set it to invisible if desired. If the browser freezes, the problem is elsewhere (e.g. you tried using the code without adding the `span` to the document; it won't work, since its width will remain zero then).